# Fuzzy matching with long sentence(s)

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, fuzzy-search, fuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
ID       CompanyName         JobDescription
1        Green Grass LLC     "In the centre of Green Grass area..."
2        Johnny Inc.          "Johnny is currently looking for data analist that..."
3        Liamloy             "LiamLoy Corp. is established in New York..."
4        KaasKan             "In the forest we are walking..."
```

My main goal is to exclude the `CompanyName` in each `JobDescription`. The desired output would be:

```
ID       CompanyName         JobDescription
1        Green Grass LLC     "In the centre of area..."
2        Johnny Inc.          "is currently looking for data analist that..."
3        Liamloy             "is established in New York..."
4        KaasKan             "In the forest we are walking"
```

I have tried to `word tokenize` the `JobDescription` (convert the sentence in to words) and apply `fuzzymatching` to detect and remove the matches. However, this was not very successful. For example, when tokenizing the third `JobDescription`. "`Liamloy`" is compared to "`LiamLoy`" and "`Corp`.". Maybe this approach is not ideal. I have no idea at this point. I wonder if any of you would like to share their opinion and enlighten me how I can succesfully remove the `CompanyName` in each `JobDescription`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't expect the words in the company names to be swapped, I suggest using the built-in python library [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) to find the common part of two strings and replace it with a mask.

```
def find_matching_spans(a, b, min_match=3, max_mismatch=1):
    """ Find the spans in the string b that are similar to the string a"""
    prev_match = 0
    match = 0
    mismatch = 0
    i = 0
    span_start = 0
    prev_start = 0
    span_end = 0
    spans = []
    common = []
    
    def add_span():
        if prev_match > min_match:
            if spans and spans[-1][-1] >= prev_start - 2:
                spans[-1][-1] = span_end
            else:
                spans.append([prev_start, span_end])
    
    for item in difflib.ndiff(a.lower(), b.lower()):
        if item[0] == ' ' and item[2] != ' ':
            match += 1
            mismatch = 0
            if match == 1:
                span_start = i
                common = []
            common.append(item[2])
        elif item[0] == '+' or item[2] == ' ':
            if match > min_match:
                add_span()
                prev_start = span_start
                prev_match = match
                span_end = i
            match = 0
            mismatch += 1
            if mismatch > max_mismatch:
                add_span()
                prev_match = 0
        elif item[0] == '-':
            pass
        if item[0] in {' ', '+'}:
            i += 1
    return spans


def replace_spans(text, spans, replacement):
    spans = [[0, 0]] + spans + [[len(text), len(text)]]
    parts = []
    for i in range(1, len(spans)):
        parts.append(text[spans[i-1][1]:spans[i][0]])
        if i < len(spans) - 1:
            parts.append('XXX')
    return ''.join(parts)


def replace_name(a, b, replacement='XXX'):
    b_prev = None
    while b_prev != b:
        spans = find_matching_spans(a, b)
        b_prev = b
        b = replace_spans(b, spans, replacement)
    return b
```

It will work like this:

```
print(replace_name("Green Grass LLC", "In the centre of Green Grass area..."))
print(replace_name("Johnny Inc.", "Johnny is currently looking for data analist that..."))
print(replace_name("Liamloy", "LiamLoy Corp. is established in New York..."))
print(replace_name("KaasKan", "In the forest we are walking..."))
```

And produce the output

```
In the centre of XXX area...
XXX is currently looking for data analist that...
XXX Corp. is established in New York...
In the forest we are walking...
```

Comment: This only works for short sentences. Somehow it does not work for long sentences. Appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regex?

```py
import re


def replace_company_name(company_name, text):
    sanitized_text = re.sub(company_name, '', text)
    return sanitized_text
```

It sounds like you also need to consider company name post-fixes like corp, due to the example with Liamloy.

One way to deal with this is a common set of company name post-fix constant. You should also note that I am using the ignore case flag because looking at the row for Liamloy, the company name is Liamloy, while in the job description it is LiamLoy. There are also likely differences in how the post-fixes are capitalized (INC, Inc, inc, etc )

```py
COMPANY_NAME_POSTFIXES = '|'.join(['INC', 'CORP', 'LLC', 'LTD'])


def replace_company_name(company_name, text):

    # 1. replace any postfixes in the company name. E.G. Green Grass LLC. -> Green Grass 
    company_name_post_fixregex = rf'({COMPANY_NAME_POSTFIXES})?\\.?'
    sanitized_company_name = re.sub(company_name_postfix_regex, '', company_name, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    # 2. replace any instances of the sanitized company name followed optionally by both a space and a company name postfix
    search_string = rf'{sanitized_company_name}\\s?{company_name_postfix_regex}'
    sanitized_text = re.sub(search_string, '', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return sanitized_text
```

The above approach will lead to the side effect of replacing instances of words being used if they aren't the company name. E.g. for Green Grass LLC     "In the centre of Green Grass area there is a lot of green grass that is cared for" -> In the centre of area there is a lot of that is cared for

If this side effect is not desired, you will need to sanitize the job description for the capitalization of the company name or calculate and pass in an array of company names.